# NEST - Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to connect like with **mongodb**, through the **nest** module. But when I pass the user and password parameters the connection is not made. But without the username and password parameters, a connection is made.

```
MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://username:pass!@127.0.0.1:22587/test')
ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database.


MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:22587/test')
LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't that I was passing the d parameters in the wrong place.

```
MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:22587',
    {
        user: dbUser
        pass: dbPass
    }
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ I've flagged your answer because it is only a reply to the previous answer where you have already commented.  The answer section of an SO post is reserved specifically for attempts to answer the post question.  If you think the content of this answer should be added to your question then you should add it there. Please visit SO Help Center and specifically this guideline for more details >>> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer